# Prometheus - CPU Load for a period of time

Tags: prometheus, cpu, cpu-usage, promql, cpu-load

I'm trying to find the CPU load of my servers, on a 15m average for the last 60 days.

And I would like to define a server, as under-utilized:

- If usage is below 10% during this period
- If usage is below 50% and variance is low

I thought maybe calculate the **max_over_time**, and check if usage is less than 10% :

```
max_over_time(node_load15{instance="ServerOne",job="events_prometheus"}[60d])
```

But I'm not sure if this is getting me the correct results, and also, the variance is not taken into account here..

How would you get this data using Prometheus?